# How to insert in Joomla module a menu made with JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, menu

I want to insert a menu in the Main Menu of Joomla 3.x. This menu uses CSS and JavaScript technology. How could I do this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Joomla documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to directly edit the template you are using.
Seeking information about "using template overrides in Joomla"

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you should:

**1)** Add the new menu

**2)** Generate a new .css file with your css code, let's call it "override.css"

**3)** Generate a new js file with your JS stuff, let's call it "scripts.js"

**4)** Add the css to your template, edit:
/joomla/templates/your-template/index.php

Add this line:

```
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/override.css');
```

- Add it after line 40 approximately or after any other JS scripts the template includes.

**5)** Add the js to your template, edit:
/joomla/templates/your-template/index.php

Add the following line:

```
$doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/scripts.js');
```

- Add it after line 43 approximately or after any other CSS styles the template includes.

This step by step would work perfectly with both **beez3** and **protostar** template from the Joomla default code.

And should probably work with any other.